# How do I fix this error TypeError: _components_firebase_Firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.auth is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js

I am using Firebase with next.js and I have the files set up like below. I am trying to use the firebase client side sdk but it does not seem to be working on the sign up.

Firebase.js where the firebase app is initialized

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
const config = {
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

export default function initFirebase() {
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    
    firebase.initializeApp(config)
  }
}
```

The function which is erroring on the sign up paenter code herege.

```
import Firebase from "../../components/firebase/Firebase";

    Firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
                            // Handle Errors here.
                            
                           
                          });
```

Comment: My code is similar except my firebase import line reads `import * as firebase from "firebase/app";` It's been working until this morning when I upgraded the firebase package to v7.20.0. I got the same 'auth is not a function' error. I downgraded the firebase package to v7.19.1 and error is gone. I'm guessing a bug in this firebase package version?

Comment: how did you down grade your firebase package

Comment: You can just run `npm install firebase@7.19.0` or, in your package.json file, set the firebase entry to read `"firebase": "7.19.1"`, removing the caret symbol from the front of the version number, then re-run `npm install` to reinstall all your packages. Just don't forget to check for future upgrades to see if this issue gets fixed.

Comment: I posted my own question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63942989/getting-error-typeerror-firebase-auth-is-not-a-function-as-of-the-release-of). For what it's worth, I was playing around with the versions of other dependencies to see if anything impacted the issue when the code suddenly started working for me again. I tried isolating the fix, but could _not_ reproduce the problem! Very frustrating! I'm thinking there might have been something wonky with the command shell and should have just restarted it earlier. It's just weird! Whatever, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't export anything from Firebase.js called `auth`.  That's what the error message is trying to tell you.  If you don't export it, you can't access it after an import.

If you want to access the auth() function from the global firebase namespace, consider exporting it:

```
export function auth() {
    return firebase.auth();
}
```

Then you can import it in another source file:

```
import { auth } from "../../components/firebase/Firebase";
auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(...);
```

In general, you should avoid using `default` exports as you're using now.  It's far better to name each export individually.  You can also consider exporting the entire `firebase` namespace if you want to expose the entire SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your Firebase.js module is that you're exporting your `initFirebase` function rather than `firebase` itself.

Try changing that bottom section to:

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config)
}

export default firebase;
```

*P.S. When I first saw your post, I was hung up on a seemingly similar problem of my own causing me to overlook this export issue when I made my comments. I should have caught this export issue earlier. This is my lesson to myself about not jumping to conclusions.*