# Getting error "TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function" as of the release of v7.20.0 of the firebase-js-sdk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building a Reactjs app using Create React App, that uses Firebase's auth and firestore services. I have a module that loads the firesbase services:

```
var firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/auth');
require('firebase/firestore');
require('firebase/performance');

if (firebase.apps.length < 1) {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "..."
  });
}

export const fbAuth = firebase.auth();
export const db = firebase.firestore();

export default firebase;
```

This code worked until yesterday when I upgraded the firebase package from v7.19.1 to v7.20.0.

I'm running Create React App's `npm start` script which is using its webpack config to compile the app. Immediately following the firebase upgrade, my app displays the compile error "TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function" highlighting my `export const fbAuth = firebase.auth();` line of code.

If I downgrade the firebase-js-sdk version to 7.19.1, my app compiles and runs with no problems.

Is this a bug in the latest firebase package? Or has the upgrade exposed a quirk in Create React App's webpack config? Or is my code weird? Anybody know what's happening here?

Comment: Firebase-js-sdk v7.21.0 was released yesterday, but problem persists. :(

Answer (score 0):

I created some other simple projects using this same code and it worked properly. Thinking the issue might be caused by other dependencies, I played around with their installed versions, deleting node_modules then running `npm install` for a fresh install. For a long time, nothing worked then, suddenly, my app *did* start working. I undid the last change I made thinking to pinpoint the problem... only to find I can't even reproduce the problem again! WTF? Maybe something wonky within my command shell environment? Not sure. Guess it pays to reboot now and again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this import firebase from "firebase"

This only works if you if you installed firebase tools.

Comment: Or I can leave it exactly as is. I answered (in a post) my own question yesterday finding the issue appeared to be elsewhere and the original problem is resolved. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hope your app goes well. Can you sub to my yt channel it is called DevGenix.